# React-router v4. Does "exact" prop forbid any nested Route?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-v4

I have noticed, that if I create `<Route path={'/'} exact component={Profile} />` I can't nest any other  inside  component just because that prop "exact" prevents any matching and stop rendering .

What I'm trying to build is a simple app with Profile and Orders pages. Each page has it's own sidebar and some list of order items. I use nested routes inside each pages to redern proper order list depending on current location. To make this app perfect I need to render Profile page on starting location (for example, 'https://myapp.com').

I read all docs and the only solution is to use "exact" prop in Route component. But that is too fragile solution, because if I would like to use nested routes for sidebar or order list deinition.

Is there any other way to build a routing that can show Profile page on 'https://myapp.com' location but also allow me to use nested routes?

My current implementation is next:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={'/'} exact component={Profile} />
   <Route path={'/orders'} component={Orders} />
   <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>

class Profile extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className='profile_page'>
            <Profile_Bar />

            <div className='content'>
               <Switch>
                  <Route path={'/subscribers'} component={User_List} />
                  <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
               </Switch>
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

class Orders extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className='orders_page'>
            <Orders_Bar />

            <div className='content'>
               <Switch>
                  <Route path={'/active'} component={Orders_List} />
                  <Route path={'/completed'} component={Orders_List} />
               </Switch>
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

const NotFound = ({ location }) => (
  <div>
    NotFound {location.pathname}
  </div>
)
```

In my old realisation I use `<Redirect />` instead:

```
<Switch>
   <Redirect from='/' to='/profile'/>
   <Route path={'/profile'} component={Profile} />
   <Route path={'/orders'} component={Orders} />
   <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code of the route? Also, what do you mean by 'nested routes' ?

Comment: Thank u. I have done this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally your **Profile** component would be handled at its own route like '/profile' and create, a separate component, say **Home**, for your '/' route:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={'/'} exact component={Home} />
  <Route path={'/profile'} component={Profile} />
  <Route path={'/orders'} component={Orders} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

...and then your **Profile** component would have sub routes like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={'/profile/subscribers'} component={User_List} />
  <Route path={'/profile/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

---

If you really don't want the 'profile' in the route paths then you could add you '/subscribers' and '/dashboard' routes to your main routes, which both render the **Profile** component but you would probably still want to handle the '/' route with its own component:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={'/'} exact component={Home} />
  <Route path={'/subscribers'} component={Profile} />
  <Route path={'/dashboard'} component={Profile} />
  <Route path={'/orders'} component={Orders} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

---

I suppose another option would be to change the order of your routes so that '/orders' matches before '/'. You can then remove **exact** from the '/' route so that the sub routes also match.

In this case, though, you will have to handle your **NotFound** route in the **Profile** component, which is not ideal.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={'/orders'} component={Orders} />
  <Route path={'/'} component={Profile} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is a good solution. I'll try it